# Replace multi-byte character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, hex

Im trying to replace no-break space copied from Word with normal space, however nothing seem to work for me.

I have tried reading this space as unicode and hexadecimal, then replace it with normal. According to https://unicode-table.com/en/202F/ it is Narrow No-Break Space, but it look like this space is more than one character.

input.html looks like this (2x Narrow No-Break Space in front):

```
  n
```

My script:

```py
with open('input.html', 'r+') as f:
    copy = f.read()

for line in copy:
    for char in line:
        print(char, hex(ord(char)), end = ' ')
        print(repr(char), ord(char))
```

Gives output:

```py
â 0xe2 'â' 226
€ 0x20ac '€' 8364
Ż 0x17b 'Ż' 379
â 0xe2 'â' 226
€ 0x20ac '€' 8364
Ż 0x17b 'Ż' 379
n 0x6e 'n' 110
```

Tried to replace spaces with:

```py
copy.replace(u"\u202f", ".")
copy.replace("\0xe2\0x20ac\0x17b", ".")
copy.replace(' ', '.')
```

and many more configurations, but nothing seems to actually work.

I'd like to have all no-break spaces as normal spaces in html file but I have no idea how to do it.

## Edit:

Replaced spaces with:

```py
copyb = bytes(copy, 'utf8')
copyb = copyb.replace(b'\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xbb', b'.')
```

but since (if I'm right) copyb is an object, I don't understand why replace() doesn't work in my case simply this way (Python 3.7):

```py
copyb = bytes(copy, 'utf8')
copyb.replace(b'\xc3\xa2\xe2\x82\xac\xc5\xbb', b'.')
```

Comment: `s.replace('\u202f', ' ')` works for me.  However your example output looks like mojibake - are you sure you using the right encoding to decode the input file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this space is more than one character.

This space is more than one *byte*. UTF8 characters can be [up to 4 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

### Bytes vs Strings

There also seems to be some confusion about the difference between strings and bytes objects. Eli Bendersky has a good article on [the difference](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3). To refer to a non-printable character in a bytes object, preface the two hex numbers by \x like '\x12', not '\0x12'.

For 0xe2, you might be thinking of a *hex* number, which is an int representation:

```
>>> 0x10
16
```

### Replacing narrow no-break space

Your question is about replacing this character, so let's do that.

#### In a String

```py
>>> mystr = 'a\u202fb'
>>> print(mystr)
a b
>>> mystr.replace('\u202f', '.')
'a.b'
```

#### In a Bytes Object

```py
>>> mybytes = bytes('a\u202fb', 'utf8')
>>> print(mybytes)
b'a\xe2\x80\xafb'
>>> mybytes.replace(b'\xe2\x80\xaf', b'.')
b'a.b'
```

Comment: Thank You for great explanation and link to the article, it really helped!

Comment: Glad to hear! Keep in mind for your Edit that [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) only works on strings or bytestrings, so a generic "object" doesn't necessarily have a replace method.